# What could "reason: Layer6 timeout" possibly mean?

Tags: haproxy

I have a haproxy configured with two servers in the backend. Occasionally, every 16-20h one of them gets marked by haproxy as DOWN:

```
haproxy.log-20190731:2019-07-30T16:16:24+00:00 <local2.alert> haproxy[2716]: Server be_kibana_elastic/kibana8 is DOWN, reason: Layer6 timeout, check duration: 2000ms. 0 active and 0 backup servers left. 8 sessions active, 0 requeued, 0 remaining in queue.
```

I did some reading how haproxy runs the checks but the Layer6 timeout does not tell me much. What could be a possible reasons for that timeout? What does it actually mean?

Here is my backend configuration

```
backend be_kibana_elastic
    balance roundrobin
    stick   on src
    stick-table  type ip size 100k expire 12h
    server kibana8 172.24.0.1:5601 check ssl verify none
    server kibana9 172.24.0.2:5601 check ssl verify none
```

Answer (score 4):

Layer 6 refers to TLS.  The backend is accepting a TCP connection but isn't negotiating TLS (SSL) on the health check connection within the allowed time.

The configuration values `timeout connect`, `timeout check`, and `inter` all interact to determine how much time health checks are allowed, to complete, and the default value of `inter` if not specified is 2000 milliseconds, which is what you're seeing here.  By default, `inter` (health check interval) determines both how often checks run and how long they are allowed to complete.

Since you have not configured a `fall` count for the servers, the implication is that the default value 3 is being used, which means your server is actually failing 3 consecutive health checks, before being marked down.

Consider adding `option log-health-checks` to the backend declaration, which will create additional log entries of those initial failing checks before the final one causes the backend to be marked down.

Increasing the allowable time may avoid the failure, but is probably valid only for testing -- not a fix -- because if your backend can't reliably respond to a check within 2000 ms, then it also can't reliably respond to client connections within that time frame, which is a long time to wait for a response.

Note that in typical environments, intermittent packet loss will typically cause sluggish behavior in increments of 3000 ms, because TCP stacks often use a retransmission timeout (RTO) of 3 seconds.  Since this is more than 2000 ms, packet loss on your network is one possible explanation for the problem.

Another possible explanation is excessive CPU load on the backend, either related to traffic or to a cron job doing something intensive, because TLS negotiation -- relatively speaking -- is an expensive process from the CPU's perspective.

Comment: Thanks! What would you suggest could be the reason for the backend server no to respond to SSL negotiation?

Comment: I've added some additional information to the answer that may be useful.

Comment: Excellent, thank you! You are a real person, not a bot, right?

Comment: Tempting though it is to respond with an answer that implies I am a bot, I am a real person.  The name was inspired during my days as a DBA.